# Non-square matrices using glm

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

I want to define and calculate the pseudo-inverse of a 3x4 matrix using the library [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/code.html). However their documentation is not the most detailed I've seen. All examples cover only square matrices.

Is it possible to define a 3x4 matrix something like `glm::mat(3,4)` and fill it with zeros? If not - is there any other library that lets me do this?

Comment: GLM supports a `mat3x4` type. It would be surprising if there were no way to fill it with zeros.

Comment: Thanks, have you seen any documentation on how to do declare this mat3x4?

Comment: Look in Section 1.1 of this PDF to get started: http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/glm-0.9.7.pdf

Comment: @Logicrat thanks, this pdf was very useful